# Can I have a table that spans multiple pages using ctable?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, ctable

I'm currently working on a paper and I have a bunch of tables.  Currently I'm using the `ctable` package for my tables. One of my tables is rather long and it spans more than one page. However currently the table is kinda being cut off. My question is, is there a way to make `ctable` behave like `longtable`?

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: longtable provides captions and footnotes which appear to be the main things added by ctable for floating tables. Is there any reason for not just using longtable?

Answer (score 3):

The package doesn't provide such a possibility. The package uses `minipage` which makes it difficult to change the internal code. However I think switching to `longtable` isn't very hard.

Comment: And how do I switch to *longtable*. Just replacing *ctable* everywhere with *longtable* does not do the job.